# background image size reducing in IE10 from IE9 (java code)

Tags: html, css, jsp, internet-explorer

This is an example of an application I am trying.
The GUI of this should be the same in IE10(without compatibility mode) as it is in IE9. But in IE10, the background image for the 'ADD' label is reducing in size. 
I am not able to find the exact reason for this.
Few solutions suggested that I have to give explicit 'height' and 'width' parameters , but that is also not helping.

I am not understanding what I am doing in a wrong way. Thanks.
The jsp code is as below:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
 .buttonM{
  color: red;
  padding-top: 4px;
  font-family: "Verdana";
  font-size: 8pt;
  cursor: hand;
  background-image:url("images/buttonM.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

 .buttonMOver{
  color: white;
  padding-top: 4px;
  font-family: "Verdana";
  font-size: 8pt;
  cursor: hand;
  background: url("images/buttonM.png") no-repeat ;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

  table, th, td{
   border: 1px solid black;
  }

  label{
  height: 23; 
  text-align: center
  }
 </style>
 <script>
   function fnButtonClicked(){
     alert("button clicked");
   }
 </script>
 <title>trial</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <meta name="GENERATOR"
   content="Rational® Application Developer for WebSphere® Software">
 </head>
 <body>
   <table>
     <tr height="40">
       <td>
        Name:
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text">
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr height="40">
       <td>
        Number:
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text">
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr height="40">
       <td align="center" colspan="2">
         <label class="buttonM"
                style="width: 80; height: 23;"
                onmouseover="this.className='buttonMOver';"
                onmouseout="this.className='buttonM';"
                onclick="javascript:showDetailsPopUp();">
                ADD
          </label>
       </td>                
     </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used 'div' tag instead of the 'label' tag. Solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like you haven't set width param of element, so it's set to the default which is only as much as your text representation. I usually had such problems with IE when I missed width/height or some element.

Try setting width and height params in button style and  where the button is located.

```
<label class="buttonM"
            style="width: 80px; height: 23px;">
```

You define width and height in pixels (usually). This could be it aswell. In top section yuo defined them in pixels at least. Later on you seem to forgot about it.

Try to change `<td align="center" colspan="2">` to `<td align="center" colspan="2" width="80" height="23">`

Try to add width to label class:

```
label{
  height: 23 px ; <-- missing px unit 
  text-align: center;
  width: 80 px ;
  }
```

You could also define your TR tag to avoid writing same stuff all over again:

```
tr{
  height: 40px;
}
```

It's simplier to modify stuff later on.

You can also change `padding-top: 4px;` to: `padding: 4px 20px 4px 20px;` here:

```
.buttonM{
  color: red;
  padding-top: 4px;
```

Comment: there isn't any seperate button added. Its a label class inside a table cell which has the text. So I have given height and width parameters to that which din't help. Do you mean to say I shoul add these parameters in the 'buttonM' class ?

Comment: you missed the pixel unit after defining button dimensions

Comment: Did changing label class style help?

Comment: you are right that the background size is taking the width of the label, so I tried put '&nbsp' i.e. space character so the size is increasing. But that is not the right  way to do it right? Also I tried the above ways but nothing is changing.

Comment: Could you update your code with the changes I suggested?